# How do I access files in same directory as executable? (Python Catkin)

Tags: catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a python catkin package in which I am trying to run some shell files kept in the same `src` folder as my main executable python file `start.py`.
However, unless I do `rosrun` from the `src` folder, the python code is unable to find the shell files for execution. I keep getting a `File Not Found` error on my script.
I tried adding these to the `include` folder and updated my `CMakeLists.txt` but that didn't work. How do I access these shell files?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/236116/how-do-i-access-files-in-same-directory-as-executable?-(python-catkin)/) by [Nightstalker](https://answers.ros.org/users/20256/nightstalker/) on ROS Answers with karma: 35 on 2016-06-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I agree with @gvdhoorn about avoiding relative path names. The trick is to use [rospkg](http://wiki.ros.org/Packages#Python) to construct a path relative to your package directory, something like this (*untested*):

```
import os, rospkg
rp = rospkg.RosPack()
script_path = os.path.join(rp.get_path("your_package"), "src", "script_name")
```

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2016-06-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Nightstalker](https://answers.ros.org/users/20256/nightstalker/) on 2016-06-06**:
This works! Thanks a lot, didn't know this trick till now.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-06-07**:
Note that this will only work in the *source* and *devel* spaces: packages typically don't `install(..)` the contents of the `pkg/src` directory, resulting in a non-existent path whenever the snippet @joq posted is run in a node started from an *install* space.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2016-06-07**:
A good point. It would be better to put them in a `scripts/` folder and install that.

**Comment by [Nightstalker](https://answers.ros.org/users/20256/nightstalker/) on 2016-06-11**:
Took your advice, installed my API scripts in `scripts` folder and kept the shell files in a `data` folder. Added both to my `CMakeLists.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

See if [Unable to read a file while using relative path](http://answers.ros.org/question/235337) helps.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-06-06

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2